# Quando é que as armas brancas ficaram “brancas”?

Tags: origem-histórica

Andamos por aí às voltas com as espadas ultimamente, e veio-me à cabeça esta questão: quando é que aparece a designação *arma branca?* Segundo o [Aulete *arma branca* é:](http://www.aulete.com.br/arma)

> Qualquer arma formada por lâmina de metal, cortante ou perfurante.

Imagino que o nome tenha surgido depois do aparecimento das armas de fogo e por oposição a elas. Talvez por as lâminas serem amoladas regularmente e ficarem brilhantes.

Portanto o que eu quero saber é: quais e de quando são os primeiros registos de *arma branca*? Existe informação mais sólida acerca da origem da expressão do que a minha especulação acima? Será que a expressão foi invenção nossa ou empréstimo de outra língua?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo [um conhecido estudioso do Português](http://sualingua.com.br/2015/05/23/arma-branca/) as teorias apresentadas pelo autor desta questão são corretas! Diz Claudio Moreno, a respeito do surgimento de *arma branca*:

> A partir do séc. XVIII, com o desenvolvimento da pistola, do arcabuz e
> do canhão, o conceito arma ganhou duas subespécies: as armas de fogo,
> que usam a energia da pólvora, e as armas brancas, geralmente dotadas
> de lâmina, que dependem da força e do braço humano.
>
> Bem nessa época, o
> dicionário de Bluteau (é de 1720) distingue as armas de fogo das armas
> brancas, chamadas assim, diz ele,  “porque eram de aço branqueado ou
> prateado” (é útil lembrar que branco vem do Germano *blanck*,
> “reluzente, polido, branco”, o que combina perfeitamente com a
> aparência do aço).
>
> A expressão arma branca, portanto, nada mais é do
> que um dos primeiros exemplos de retronímia (ou retroformação, como
> querem alguns).

Extraindo do texto acima respostas para os questionamentos feitos pelo OP:

> Pergunta:  Imagino que o nome tenha surgido depois do aparecimento das armas de
> fogo
>
> Resposta: Correto! A expressão arma branca, nada mais é do que um dos primeiros exemplos de *retronímia*. A *retronímia*, por sua vez, ocorre com o surgimento de uma novidade que deflagra a necessidade de rebatizar o termo antigo, genérico, acrescentando-lhe um especificador. Não raro o elemento novo termina “roubando” o termo para si, ficando o elemento antigo reduzido a uma simples subespécie.

2a pergunta:

> Pergunta: (é chamada de *arma branca*) Talvez por as lâminas serem amoladas regularmente e ficarem  brilhantes.
>
> Reposta: Correto! Sendo a origem do termo, provavelmente, o Germano *blanck*

3a pergunta:

> Pergunta: quais e de quando são os primeiros registos de arma branca?
>
> Resposta: Não sei se necessariamente é o mais antigo, mas em 1720 o termo *arma branca* foi registrado no dicionário de Bluteau.

Por fim incentivo a todos a leitura do [artigo completo](http://sualingua.com.br/2015/05/23/arma-branca/), pois é elucidativo a este respeito.

Comment: Excelente. Isto já vem no [Bluteau  (letra A) de 1712](http://purl.pt/13969/4/l-2771-a/l-2771-a_item4/l-2771-a_PDF/l-2771-a_PDF_24-C-R0090/l-2771-a_0000_capa-capa_t24-C-R0090.pdf). 1720 é capaz de ser edição posterior, não sei: “Armas brancas. Chamaraõlhe assi, porque eraõ de aço branqueado, ou prateado como as dos principes; com ellas andavaõ os homens cubertos desde a cabeça até os pés, a saber com morriaõ (?) ou capacete, com viseira, com peyto & espaldar, & manoplas, grevas, &c.” Curiosamente, só lista equipamento defensivo.